# Mysql Galera Autostart from boot --wsrep-new-cluster

Tags: mysql, galera

To recover from a blackout I need to start the Galera cluster when the system boots and I can only do this with the following:

```
service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
```

"service mysql start" will get launched on boot but will fail because it is the only one in the cluster. How do I get the cluster to start from boot and not fail if it is the only one there?

EDIT

Looks like I have to leave gcomm:// blank for it to start but it is not the best solution as if another server came online first then it would fail.

```
#galera settings
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="my_wsrep_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_provider_options="pc.bootstrap=true"
```

Comment: Yes.. I used a startup script that would stop the first node then start it using --wsrep-new-cluster then it would ssh (using certificates so no login) to the other nodes stop the node and then start them in order. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to edit init scripts - This is solution for debian - location my init script is /etc/init.d/mysql
then I found this line:

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe "${@:2}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and I added parameter --wsrep-new-cluster

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --wsrep-new-cluster "${@:2}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and it is working after boot.

Comment: Hi Stanley. Thanks for the answer here. Do you know if this will be permanent or will it be overwritten with an upgrade?

Comment: It depends mainly on your distribution package system. But even on debian there are multiple ways to upgrade your system and I strongly recommend thinking about every modification of your config file during an upgrade.

Comment: It seems fine, but what if the node with `--wsrep-new-cluster` is not the first node in cluster? I mean what if all the another nodes are fine, but just the old first one reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I've been through this before.  The following is the procedure I documented for my co-workers:

- First we will determine the node with the latest change

  - On each node go to /var/lib/mysql and examine the grastate.dat file
  - We are looking for the node with the highest seqno and a uuid that is not all zeros
- On the node that captured the latest change startup the cluster in bootstrap mode

  - service mysql bootstrap
- Startup the other nodes via the usual startup command

  - service mysql start
- Check each node if they have the same DB list

  - mysql -u root -p
  - show databases;
- On any node run the command to check for the status of the cluster and ensure you see something like the following

  - wsrep_local_state_comment | Synced <-- cluster is synced
  - wsrep_incoming_addresses | 10.0.0.9:3306,10.0.0.11:3306,10.0.0.13:3306 <-- all nodes are providers
  - wsrep_cluster_size | 3 <-- cluster consists of 3 nodes
  - wsrep_ready | ON <-- good :)